# Using the camera on 64bit vs. 32bit from Java

Tags: python, camera, java, 64-bit, libcamera

I have Raspberry Pi 3 B. And a camera module v. 2.1.
I have installed the Raspbian OS 64bit, the latest - "bullseye"

Tried to record some video in any way, and after some experimentation, I found out that:

- The 64bit can't work with Python bindings, as I found in the docs. I've tried the omnipresent .py snippet and it says it can't find `libmmal`.
- The 64bit Raspbian OS can't have the "legacy stack" enabled, as the `raspi-config` tool told me.
- The `raspivid` and `raspistill` apps are not present in the image or installable from the repo. Is that unsupported for 64bit?
- The `libcamera-*` apps supposed to replace the "legacy stack" works, but is rather limited and can't store the frames to memory, AFAICT.
- The Java projects rely on `ProcessBuilder` which just calls the legacy stack binaries.

After writing this, I will go and "downgrade" to 32-bit. But in the meantime, I have a couple of questions:

- When is the support for Python bindings coming for the 64bit release?
- Does it give any performance benefit if I use 64bit? Specifically regarding video recording? On Intel CPUs it does.
- What would be the best approach to capture videos from Java / Kotlin? The `ProcessBuilder` approach does not seem to be optimal. Is there any project directly integrating over JNI? I have found a BirdJ based project [Webcam Capture](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) but that was rather obsolete.
- Should I have I2C enabled or not? `libcamera-vid` mentions it when getting an image. But the Raspberry config documentation warns that enabling it may cause issues with camera.

Comment: 64-bit for all pi3 has always been lacking and it was intended to die 32bit... that said, someone might implement what you seek someday.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Right, it's a bit too broad. I will reword it next month.